when debugging vitest unittest with vscode the Debug Console cannot access imported modules
I'm using vitest+vue3. When launching the debugger with launch.json pressing F5, in my Debug Console I can use modules imported by the script i'm debugging no problem.
but when I want to do the same but launching the debugger from one of my vitest test file *.spec.ts I get an error
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: myImportedFunction is not defined
    at eval (repl:1:1)

here is my config:
vitest.config.ts:
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import { configDefaults, defineConfig, mergeConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import viteConfig from './vite.config'

export default mergeConfig(
  viteConfig,
  defineConfig({
    test: {
      environment: 'happy-dom',
      exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, 'cypress/*', 'build/*'],
      root: fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url)),
      setupFiles: ['./src/test-utils/vitest-setup.ts'],
    },
  })
)

vite.config.ts:
import presetIcons from '@unocss/preset-icons'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'node:path'
import UnoCSS from 'unocss/vite'
import Component from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'



// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Component(),
    UnoCSS({
      presets: [presetIcons()], // Presets
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}/`,
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: process.env.PORT ? Number(process.env.PORT) : 5173,
    hmr: true,
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    entries: ['cypress/e2e/*.cy.ts']
  }
})

tsconfig.vitest.json:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "lib": [],
    "types": ["node", "happy-dom"]
  }
}

